# Non-flicker interactive Image sequence display with wxpython

Tags: python, image, wxpython, interactive

I've created an interactive image sequence viewer. The viewer would work almost perfectly only if there is no flickering. I read a bit about [double buffering](http://wiki.wxpython.org/DoubleBufferedDrawing) and find it a bit confusing. I need straight on explanation/code what should I do to remove flickering in my program. In most of the examples there is an explanation for resizing. I in other hand do not need that, my window is size-fixed. So what approach should I take to fix the flickering?

Code:

```
import wx

class main_frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Main window', size=(1300, 750))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.Centre()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.Frames = []
        l=1
        while l < 365:
            self.Frames.append(wx.Image('images/{0}.png'.format(l), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
            print l
            l+=1
        self.slider = wx.Slider(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, size = (500,-1))
        self.slider.SetMax(356)
        l = self.slider.GetValue()

        self.image = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel,-1,wx.BitmapFromImage(self.Frames[l]))

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_v = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer_v.Add(self.image, 0, wx.CENTRE | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer_v.Add(self.slider, 0, wx.CENTRE | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer_v, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.OnSlider, self.slider)

    def OnSlider(self,e):
        l = self.slider.GetValue()
        self.image.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(self.Frames[l]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = main_frame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wx.StaticBitmap works best when it is **static**, as in unchanging.  I think instead of using a wx.StaticBitmap I would use a panel that binds a handler for the `EVT_PAINT` event.  When you want the image to change you just do something like `self.panel.currentBitmap = self.Frames[i]` followed by a `self.panel.Refresh()`.  (Or even better would be to move that functionality into the panel class for better encapsulation.)  Then in the `EVT_PAINT` handler you just get the `wx.PaintDC` and do a `DrawBitmap` of the current bitmap.  Also, I would keep bitmaps in the list instead of images to save the conversion time when moving the slider.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post a minimal code example her to answer the general question of non-flicker display of a sequence of images in wx python, since I recently was looking for the answer myself. 
The key to removing flicker when updating the bitmap is to use a BufferedPaintDC (or alternatively BufferedDC), and draw the new bitmap to this. When drawing to a BufferedPaintDC you first draw the bitmap to memory, and when finnished the buffered bitmap is drawn to screen only once.

```python
import time
import wx
import threading

def changeBitmapWorker(parent):
    img1 = 'img1.png'
    img2 = 'img2.png'
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            parent.bitmap = wx.Bitmap(img1)
        else:
            parent.bitmap = wx.Bitmap(img2)
        parent.Refresh()
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1

class Window(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        self.init_ui()
        self.mainWindow.Show()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.mainWindow = wx.Frame(None)
        self.mainWindow.SetSize((800, 510))
        self.vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel = MyPanel(self.mainWindow)
        panel.SetSizer(self.vbox1)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,id=-1)
        self.parent = parent
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.bitmap = None
        t = threading.Thread(target=changeBitmapWorker, args=(self,))
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        if self.bitmap != None:
            dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
            dc.Clear()
            dc.DrawBitmap(self.bitmap, 0,0)
        else:
            pass

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = Window()
        app.MainLoop()
```